# Database select ignore strings

Tags: php

how can I ignore certain strings with a select.
Strings like:

```
 "12345_"
```

I like get only such Strings:

```
 "12345_MyPic.jpg"
```

Or

When the select result ist like this: `"12345_"` then should be  executed another instruction.
with PHP:

```
if($image="%_"){
    echo"";
}else{
    echo"";
}
```

Thank you

Comment: I didnt understand can you edit your question a little bit? what is select?

Comment: I have a DB with structure:
Name: article
id, titel, image, content.
When there is added a Picture the image column get automaticly a String like this:
"12345_myPic.jpg".
If there is added no Picture, the image column get only this String:
"12345_"


Now iam looking for a solution to display both String in different case.

    
        if($full_image ="%_"){
    echo"dummy";
}else{
echo"helloworld";

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I understand now, many ways to do this. Maybe this will work for you:

```
$image_names = array("12345_", "12345_abc", "12345_cde", "12345_");


foreach($image_names as $image){
  if(substr($image, -1) == "_"){
     echo"dummy\n";
  }else{ 
    echo"helloworld\n"; 
  }
}
```

---

OUTPUT

```
dummy
helloworld
helloworld
dummy
```

<kbd>[DEMO](https://eval.in/120383)</kbd>

read up on [substr()](http://www.php.net/substr)